# Push notifications with new sender id and existing keystores not working in signed apk

Tags: android, push-notification

I am facing problem in push notifications. I have Unfortunately deleted my project from Google API console. Now I have created a new project on google API console and used its Sender id in project. When I make signed apk, the push notification gives error:

> Mismatch sender id.

Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you include your release SHA-1 key in google console Credentials ?

Answer (score 0):

am also facing same problem.Whenever we can change Details From Google console.We must generate new gcm/fcm token. Just Uninstall Previous app from device and Reinstall app same app and test again. Its working for me.I hope it is helpful to you.Try it...